# Trouble getting Serilog to read appsettings.json settings

Tags: c#, logging, .net-5, serilog

I have the following code in my console application.

```
// Build configuration
IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(ApplicationInfo.DataPath)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, false)
    .Build();

// Configure Serilog
string logFormat = "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt}][{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}";
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
    .WriteTo.Console(LogEventLevel.Verbose, logFormat)
    .WriteTo.File(ApplicationInfo.GetDataFileName("log"), LogEventLevel.Verbose, logFormat)
    .CreateLogger();

AppHost = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseSerilog()
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        services.AddDbContext<TTApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        });
        services.Configure<EmailSettings>(configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));
        services.Configure<SftpSettings>(configuration.GetSection("FtpSettings"));
    })
    .Build();
```

This seems to be working. However, when I add the following section to my *appsettings.json* file, I do not get any of the verbose logging from within the framework. All I get is the logging that I specifically log in my application.

```
"Serilog": {
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft": "Information",
      "System": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

As best I can tell, Serilog is ignoring these settings. How can I change that?

**Update:**

If I change the *Default* value to *Debug* in *appsettings.json*, that does in fact control whether or not my own calls to `LogDebug()` show up. But I don't understand why none of Microsoft's logging shows up. Wouldn't Microsoft's code use whatever logger is configured?

Comment: This sort of setup works for me, however, what are you expecting to happen? Are you expecting to pickup logs from the Microsoft logging provider ? Your own logs are not working?

Comment: @TheGeneral: Yes, my own logs work just fine. I was expecting it to pick up Microsoft logging. Wouldn't Microsoft's code use whatever logger was configured?

Comment: Hi! Can you post an example of one of the events that show up without the config, but that is missing when you apply it?

Answer (score 0):

While configuring a DotNet Core App, I had the same problem. I found that if I added the Nuget Package serilog-extensions-hosting, it will also start outputting the framework messages to the logs.

https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-hosting

I hope this helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).